# Sql ошибка с уникальностю id

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Когда пытаюсь вставить id в поле возникает уникальность.
Извлекал через resultset id и приболял в конце id+=1;,но не работает.
Если не трудно обьясните почему не извлекаются данные до последний записи в id.
И как сделать что бы id генерировался автоматически БД postgresql.

Код repository.

```
public void Add(String First_Name, String Last_Name, String Second_Name, String email, String password, String login) {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String sqlDate = format1.format(date);
        int id = 0;
        Connection c = getCurrentConnection();
        QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
        try {
            Statement statement = c.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM  account  ");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            }
            id += 1;
            String sql = "insert into account (id,login,password,first_name,last_name,second_name,email,active,created) values(" + "'" + id + "'" + "," +
                    "'" + login + "'" + "," + "'" + password + "'" + "," + "'" + First_Name + "'" + "," + "'" + Last_Name + "'" + "," + "'" +
                    Second_Name + "'" + "," + "'" + email + "'" + "," + "'" + "true" + "'" + "," + "'" + sqlDate + "'" + ")";
            queryRunner.update(c, sql);
            queryRunner.update(c, "insert into account_role (id,id_account,id_role) values " +
                    "(" + "'" + id + "'" + "," + "'" + id + "'" + "," + "'" + 1 + "'" + ")");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new WebtesterApplicationException(e);
        }
    }
```

---

Ошибка.

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.sql.SQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "account_pkey"

type Exception report

message java.sql.SQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "account_pkey"

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

exception.WebtesterApplicationException: java.sql.SQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "account_pkey"
  Подробности: Ключ "(id)=(2)" уже существует. Query: insert into account (id,login,password,first_name,last_name,second_name,email,active,created) values('2','password','maximbogunwork@gmail.comw2','maksim','ascsav','','maksimbogunenko1z2','true','04.02.2017') Parameters: []
    repositoryimpl.AccountRegistrationImpl.Add(AccountRegistrationImpl.java:43)
    serviceimpl.CommonServiceImpl.registration(CommonServiceImpl.java:109)
    servlet.RegistrationServlet.doPost(RegistrationServlet.java:32)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    filter.CheckLoginFilter.doFilter(CheckLoginFilter.java:39)
    filter.AbstarctFilter.doFilter(AbstarctFilter.java:22)
    filter.AutoLoginFilter.doFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:45)
    filter.AbstarctFilter.doFilter(AbstarctFilter.java:22)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "account_pkey"
  Подробности: Ключ "(id)=(2)" уже существует. Query: insert into account (id,login,password,first_name,last_name,second_name,email,active,created) values('2','password','maximbogunwork@gmail.comw2','maksim','ascsav','','maksimbogunenko1z2','true','04.02.2017') Parameters: []
    org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:392)
    org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:491)
    org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.update(QueryRunner.java:377)
    repositoryimpl.AccountRegistrationImpl.Add(AccountRegistrationImpl.java:39)
    serviceimpl.CommonServiceImpl.registration(CommonServiceImpl.java:109)
    servlet.RegistrationServlet.doPost(RegistrationServlet.java:32)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    filter.CheckLoginFilter.doFilter(CheckLoginFilter.java:39)
    filter.AbstarctFilter.doFilter(AbstarctFilter.java:22)
    filter.AutoLoginFilter.doFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:45)
    filter.AbstarctFilter.doFilter(AbstarctFilter.java:22)
```

Comment: Вам надо делать SELECT MAX(Id) FROM account

Comment: Спасибо,но почему не работал данный код разве в цыкле не извлекала  последнию запись?

Comment: Она извлекала все значения Id, но вот непонятно с какой сортировкой по умолчанию. Вам помогло если бы в вашем коде там было ORDER BY ID ASC, тогда в цикле последнее значение было бы максимальным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Записи Вашим запросом `SELECT Id FROM account` выводятся, вообще говоря, в случайном порядке. Поэтому последний id из ResultSet не обязательно будет последним использованным.

Можно заменить запрос на такой `SELECT Id FROM account ORDER BY Id`. Тогда гарантированно последний id будет действительно последним.

Но лучше такой `SELECT MAX(Id) FROM account`. Не трудно догадаться, что извлечь id сразу гораздо лучше перебора 100500-и строк.

Но и это лажа, годная в очень специфических случаях. Для генерации Id с давних пор применяются последовательности (иногда используется термин генератор).

Сначала в базе создаётся последовательность: `create sequence id_seq`.
Следующий номер извлекается функцией `nextval()`: `select nextval('id_seq')`. Каждый вызов `nextval()` возвращает новый номер больший прошлого на единицу (кстати приращение можно настраивать).

Есть несколько способов записать номер из последовательности в поле.
1) Предварительно извлечь запросом
`id = select nextval('id_seq')`
`insert into table (id, ...) values (id, ...)`
2) Использовать `nextval()` в запросе `insert`
`insert into table (id, ...) values (nextval('id_seq'), ...)`
3) объявит поле id со значением по умолчанию
`create table (id int default nextval('id_seq'), ...`
В запросе `insert` поле id не трогать `insert into table (...) values (...)`
4) И ещё один способ - поле id объявить как serial
`create table (id serial, ...`
Это является сокращением объявления последовательности и значения по умолчанию.
Т.е. в этом не надо объявлять ни последовательность, ни значение по умолчанию.

В случаях 2, 3, 4 имеются некоторые трудности определения какой id получила новая запись, если он вдруг нужен дальше в программе. Поэтому первый способ более распространённый. Но тем не менее есть способ узнать новый id используя запрос такого вида `insert into table (...) values (...) returning id`. Запрос вставит запись и вернёт её id.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо делать

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM account
```